# how to pass if else statement in django db for fetching model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

i create model name item in that some of them field can be empty some of them not so what i want to render is the model field is empty then pass and go look for another and if it has some value render without throwing error right now it will throw if request a null field so how can i fix it is there any way to do that

my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='our_items')
    subcategories = models.ForeignKey(Subcategories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='products')
    can_buy = models.ForeignKey(For, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='for_wearing')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    contain_size = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='Bagh')
    first = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    second = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    third = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    fourth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=False)
    fifth = models.ImageField(upload_to='items', blank=True)
    rating = models.FloatField(blank=False,default='4.0')
    item_vedio = models.FileField(upload_to='item_vedio', blank=True)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default='Black')
    material = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='Plastic' )
    return_policy = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default='7Days Return Policy')
    stock = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, default='In Stock')
    price = models.FloatField(blank=False,)
    actual_price = models.FloatField(blank=False)
    about_one = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=100, default='washable')
    about_two = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=100, default='Lusturous')
    offer = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now,editable=False)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my views.py

```
class Product_detail(View):
    def get(self, request, item_id):
        item = Item.objects.filter(id=item_id)
        category_list = Categories.objects.all()
        print(item)
        return render (request, 'product_detail.html',{"items" : item, 'category_list': category_list })
```

my html file

```
<section>
  {% for item in items %}
  <div class="container-fluid px-sm-1 py-5 mx-auto col-10">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="card col-5">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column thumbnails">
                    <div id="f1" class="tb tb-active"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.first.url }}"> </div>
                    <div id="f2" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.second.url }}"> </div>
                    <div id="f3" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.third.url }}"> </div>
                    <div id="f4" class="tb"> <img class="thumbnail-img fit-image" src="{{ item.fourth.url }}"> </div>
                  </div>
                <fieldset id="f11" class="active">
                    <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.first.url }}"> </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="f21" class="">
                    <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.second.url }}"> </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="f31" class="">
                    <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.third.url }}"> </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset id="f41" class="">
                    <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.fourth.url }}"> </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
              <div class="deatil_view">
                  <p class="from" style="color: blue;">{{ item.categories.name}} / <span>{{ item.subcategories.name }}</span></p>
                  <p class="back" style="float: right;"><a href="#"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Back To Site</a> </p>
                  <div class="name">
                  <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
                  <p> ( {{ item.brand_name }} )</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="rate">
                    <h4>Rating: <span style="color: #025;"> {{item.rating}}<i class="fas fa-star"></i> </span> <span style="color: #025;"> (By 100 people)</span> <span class="btn btn-success buton">✔Authentic</span> </h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="price ">
                    <h2></h2>
                    <h2>Current Price: <span style="color: #025;">{{item.price}}</span> <span style="text-decoration: line-through; color: #025;">{{item.actual_price}}</span> <span class="text-white btn btn-primary" style="font-size: 20px; padding:1px;" >{{item.offer}} off</span> </h2>
                  </div>
                  <div class="about">
                    <p class="abt">Highlights: <br>
                    Color:<span class="det">  {{ item.color }}</span> <br>
                    Material:<span class="det">  {{ item.material}}</span> <br>
                    Type:<span class="det">  {{ item.about_one }}</span> <br>
                    Type:<span class="det">  {{ item.about_two }} </span></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="replace">
                    <p class="ply">Product Policy: <span class="lpy">{{item.return_policy}}</span></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="size">
                    <input  class="radio" type="Radio" name="Size" value="S"><span class="label">S</span>
                    <input  class="radio" type="Radio" name="Size" value="M"><span class="label">M</span>
                    <input  class="radio" type="Radio" name="Size" value="L"><Span class="label">L</Span>
                    <input  class="radio" type="Radio" name="Size" value="XL"><span class="label">XL</span>
                    <input  class="radio" type="Radio" name="Size" value="2XL"><Span class="label">2XL</Span>
                    <a class="chart" href="#">Size Chart</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="button">
                  <a href="#" class="add btn btn-outline-primary btn-block">Add to Cart</a>
                  <a href="#" id="btn" class="wish btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i>Add to Whishlist</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

let me explain it to you with example if you look in the model i have item_vedio file field which can be blank so what i want if a item has a vedio field render it and if not pass the request and look for other request don not throw error like item_vedio has null value i hope no you got it

thank you for your time

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and especially how to write a [mre] (stressing on the _minimal_ part here). Your example code could have been much smaller than it currently is.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat ok i will take care next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the template, check if the field if empty or not. If it is empty then do nothing otherwise do the work.

such as for image,

```
{% if item.first %}
<fieldset id="f11" class="active">
   <div class="product-pic"> <img class="pic0" src="{{ item.first.url }}"> </div>
</fieldset>
{% endif %}
```

such way you can do it for `item_video` and it will not through any error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `item_vedio` exists using an `if` in your template.

```
{% if item.item_vedio %}
     <!-- Code when video exists -->
{% endif %}
```

This will show the Code (in between) only when video exists.